# Retrofit send json request with multiple of the same key

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

For an API I'm using, I need to send a JSON POST body request that looks like:

```
{{imdb_id:id1},{imdb_id:id2},{imdb_id:id3}}
```

where imdb_id is the string "imdb_id" and id is another string, such as "tt555555", 
I'm having trouble figuring out how to send that kind of data with Retrofit.  My first thought was to feed retrofit a list of imdb id's, but then how would it know to give each of those a key of "imdb_id"?  So what made more sense was a map as follows:

```
@POST("/notmyrealendpoint")
Observable<List<MultipleMLSearchResponse>> getMultlipleMLSearch(@Body Map<String, String> imdb_ids);
```

But I can't put multiple values in for the same key, so that doesn't work.  I saw the apache solution for MultiValuedMap, but I'm having trouble instantiating it in kotlin as it's an interface not a class, and I don't want to override all of its methods, and I'm not sure if it'll work even if I can solve that issue.

What's the idiomatic way to send such a request?

Comment: This is not a valid json, for json you need key for each of the json object
You can send these as array of json object easily though  `[{imdb_id:id1},{imdb_id:id2},{imdb_id:id3}] `

Comment: So is it that you cannot change the API that eats bad JSON? Then it is not a case of sending JSON but some general HTTP request having that body. Unless you find/make some custom Retrofit converter, maybe.